# .htaccess for clean url

Tags: php, .htaccess

I've list of states and a php file which will list all the city of the state. By taking the URL parameter as `/common.php/?state=Texas` and list all the cities.
After clicking on the city it takes the url as `/common.php/?city=Alanreed&state_code=TX` and displays the city information.

I want to format the url using .htaccess like for states it should take `state_name.html` `eg. Texas.html` and for city name either `Texas/sugar_land.html` or `tx/sugar_land.html` How can I achieve this using php and .htaccess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*).html$ common.php/?state=$1&city=$2 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.*/)?index\.html$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*).html$ common.php/?state=$1 [L]
```

`\w{2}` means 2 word characters, so it is rewritten as a state code, the second rule is to rewrite the full state names and the third is to rewrite states.

Comment: After doing this My index file is not opening. Pleas help, I do not have much knowledge about .htaccess.

Comment: Is mod rewrite enabled? And what do you mean not opening, is there an error?

Comment: Yes its enabled. Previously I've written a rule to execute .html files as .php AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .htm .html Which is working fine. After adding these 2 rules its giving server error.

Comment: Of course, the example you gave won't work (/common.php/?state=$1), the middle slash has to be removed - try the new code.

Comment: Okay thats not my problem, its not opening my index page. Its directly trying to point to common.php.

Comment: It seems to be close only thing is we've to avoid the redirection for first index page.

Comment: Don't have html files executed as php! And add something like "DirectoryIndex index.html" (w/o quotes) to your .htaccess

Comment: Thank.. Finally I've used RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*).html$ common.php/?state=$1&city=$2 [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.*/)?index\.html$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*).html$ common.php/?state=$1 [L] which is working like charm.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})\.[hH][tT][mM][lL]?$ common\.php\?state_code=$1
    RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)\.[hH][tT][mM][lL]?$ common\.php\?state=$1

    RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/([_a-zA-Z]+)\.[hH][tT][mM][lL]?$ common\.php\?state_code=$1&city=$2
    RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)/([_a-zA-Z]+)\.[hH][tT][mM][lL]?$ common\.php\?state=$1&city=$2
</IfModule>
```

Should also work for tx.htm
This assumes that your apache has mod_rewrite enabled.